# how to list all subscription names of a tenant using ARM templates?

Tags: azure, parameters, azure-resource-manager, subscription

I have a parameter called **subscription** in my custom ARM template. I want to create a drop down where all subscription should be displayed.

I tried using allowed values, But the thing is allowed values are always hard-coded and so if a subscription removes or changes or something. I have to edit the template every time.

Answer (score 0):

Add a **strongType** attribute to the parameter metadata with the value **Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions**.